# Data entry form stopped working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a data entry form that uses combo boxes with dropdown menus that was working as planned.  I created a form to display the data using a QBE created query in datasheet view. When I come back to the data entry form, everything works except it doesn't write the data to the file.

I checked the record source for the form and the control source for the comboboxes and all is as it should be. I have a date in the file that is `=Date()` for today's date, and it appears in a new record but the fields are blank.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Additional info, I did a compact and repair on the database but that didn't solve the problem. Sunday I copied everything to a new database and that didn't help.  Copied to new database again, but only the data entry form, DE queries etc. Still no luck.@$#%$#.

***New information added 6/13/16.***

After further testing, the problem lies when I tab out of the last ComboBox. So the question is, what determines a write to the file: is it tabbing out of the last control? Or what?

Comment: Additional info, I did a compact and compress on the database but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you have two forms? Does your data entry form  have a recordsource that's the same as your display form? Does your form properties show AllowAdditions = True?

Comment: There are two forms, a data entry form and a separate form the displays the data. Just saw that I have a subform in the display form and the subform has a recordsource that is a query..  But the main display form has the same recordsource as the data entry form. All forms and subform allow additions.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: It sounds like you're opening the displayform with to add a NewRecord - where's the code that opens the form?

Comment: `I created a form to display the data using a QBE created query in datasheet view`. Is your record source a table or query? if its a query, how many tables are involved in the query?

Comment: The data is put into the table in the data entry form(it was created as a data entry form) and a subform was added for space sake since I need several other controls (comboboxes). I don't think the problem is in the display form.  I copied just the data entry form and the table it adds to into a new database and left out the display form, and the same problem. The code that opens the form exists is in file options where you set the form to open when the database is opened.

Comment: Added information to original question.  See above.

Comment: It's probably because your Form cycle is set to All Records - added answer to try out

Comment: I tried changing the cycle but inconsistent results. which of the three, All Records, Currebt Record or Current page should be set to write the data to the table?  New to this, obviously. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Under Form Properties | Other

> Set Cycle to "Current Record"

Comment: I set it to "Current Record", but now it writes a record out that is blank except for the date() which is set as a default value in the table. In the LostFocus event of the last tabbed control I reset controls to visible an set all to Null.  I was assuming that that code would execute after the table was updated.  I commented out all that code and it made no difference.  But I did manage to write a couple of good records out trying things, but don't know why.  Now it just writes blanks. Thanks